# Mapping sub-domain in Godaddy, hosted at Google Cloud Platform

Tags: subdomain, godaddy, google-cloud-platform

I have been trying to map a sub-domain in *Godaddy.com* that is hosted in *Google Cloud Platform*

This is what I have done:

1) Billing and credentials are set in *Google Cloud Platform*.

2) In *Google Cloud Platform* I added a *new Cloud DNS* (Zone):

```
DNS Name: api.altura.co
Type: NS
TTL (Seconds): 21600
Data:
ns-cloud-a1.googledomains.com
ns-cloud-a2.googledomains.com
ns-cloud-a3.googledomains.com
ns-cloud-a4.googledomains.com
```

3) Then in *Godaddy* I changed:

```
Nameservers:
ns-cloud-a1.googledomains.com
ns-cloud-a2.googledomains.com
ns-cloud-a3.googledomains.com
ns-cloud-a4.googledomains.com

In the DNS Zone File:

Added a CNAME:

Host: api
Points to: ghs.googlehosted.com
TTL: 1 Hour
```

4) I waited for over 24 hours and nothing seem to happen. When I ping it I get: *Unknown host*.

I assume I may be omitting something important. Any help with this I'll highly appreciate it.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the domain name(s) in question.

Comment: @EEAA done. The real domain and subdomain were added. Let me know if you need somehting else. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

What you probably want to do in the immediate term:

1. go into GoDaddy administration and tell it to automatically manage your DNS.

   This will change your registration records to point back to GoDaddy for DNS, and will mean that visitors to your domain will get something- probably a default GoDaddy parked domain page. Right now visitors get nothing. This change will take effect pretty quickly, probably within an hour.
2. go into GCP and look up the resource to which you want to assign the api subdomain.

   This wasn't explicitly mentioned in the question but presumably there is some specific resource at GCP to which the api subdomain should resolve. This will likely be either an public IP address associated with a compute instance, or a Google-owned domain name associated with a load balancer.
3. go back into GoDaddy and assign an appropriate DNS record for the "api" subdomain- a CNAME record if what you got from Google was a domain name, or an A record if what you got was an IP address.
4. in GCP, delete the DNS configuration for api.altura.co. This is not providing any value.

It appears that you told your registrar that your authoritative DNS is at GCP, but GCP DNS does not know anything about that domain. It's not clear why this is from the information provided, but bottom line is that for basic use cases there is no reason to use GCP DNS even if GCP is used for compute or other resources.